# How to synchronize AWS DynamoDB with dataset ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito and DynamoDB.i have authenticated user using AWS Cognito and also used crud operation in DynamoDB successfully.I am creating dataset when internet is not available but i have no idea how to synchronize dataset with DynamoDB.Is AWS support dataset synchronization with DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options depending on your use-case.

The most straightforward and simple option is to use [DynamoDB streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html). It can store all updates to DynamoDB table for up to 24 hours and allows you to read these changes and reapply them in another DB.

If 24 hour window is too strict for you, you will have to create some sort of DynamoDB snapshots. Say you can create a DynamoDB snapshot every 24 hours and store it into S3. Then you can use DynamoDB streams to read real time updates and snapshots to read baseline data.

To create DynamoDB snapshots you can use [Data Pipeline service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html).

Comment: Can you subscribe to DynamoDB streams right from a client-side swift library?

Comment: Technically you should be able to do this, but only if you have a small amount of data. Any decent volume of data from DynamoDB streams will overwhelm a single iOS device. A better way is to process DynamoDB streams on the backend, extract data that you need your clients to see, and allow clients to access it. For more details please create a new question and provide more details for your use case.